# What is this cabbage-like succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents

I've seen this beautiful specimen online once before while browsing interesting-looking plants, but have forgotten its name. This one I purchased about three weeks back. What is its name and how do growers usually care for it?
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely a part of the genus Aeonium, the houseleeks. Particularly, it could be Aeonium tabuliforme. When it gets large, it may spread out like a saucer or curve down onto the ground.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a houseleek - you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sempervivum_tectorum). It is quite varied in its appearance as a group of plants, often with a pointed tip to the leaf and with red tinge to the extremity of the leaf. Yours is a round leaf type with little or no red. Water sparingly, provide sharp drainage and give good light.

Comment: Is it of the Aeonium genus? If so, I'm wondering if it could be Aeonium tabuliforme, or something else.

Comment: You could be right! Answer your own question and allow readers to vote for the answer they think is most appropriate. I think I would vote for yours.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have posted my guess as an answer.